# Finding the expected value of a random variable

Tags: statistics, definite-integrals, expected-value

I have the following question before me:
There is a project that will pay $100000-D^2$ if the project is completed in $D$ days where $D$ is a continuous random variable uniformly distributed on the interval $[60,110]$.
I want to determine the expected value of the receipts.
The problem is that I am getting two different answers from two different approaches. I am confused which one of them is correct or whether both are incorrect.
Here is what I have tried so far:

As $D$ is a continuous random variable, $R=100000-D^2$ is also a continuous random variable uniformly distributed on interval $[100000-110^2,100000-60^2]=[87900,96400]$.
Its probability density function $f_R$ is constant and equal to $1/(96400-87900)=1/8500$

Expected value of $R$ =$E[R]$= $\int_{87900}^{96400} rdr/8500= 92150$

In the second approach, I just thought of computing the average value of the function $100000-D^2$ on the interval $[60,110]$ which yielded the value $92566.67$.

The values obtained by two methods are different. What am I doing wrong here? I think that I am being wrong when I say that $R$ is uniformly distributed on interval $[87900,96400]$. But I do not know for sure. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D$ is uniformly distributed does not imply that $R$ is uniformly distributed.

Squaring doesn't preserve uniform distribution.

\begin{align}E[R]&=10^5-E[D^2]=10^5-Var(D)-E[D]^2\\&=10^5-\frac{(110-60)^2}{12}-\left(\frac{60+110}{2}\right)^2 \\&\approx92567\end{align}

Comment: Does it mean that second answer is the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach is wrong since, as you have identified, $R$ is not uniform. By [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician),

$$E[100000-D^2]=100000-\frac{1}{110-60}\int_{60}^{110}x^2dx\approx 92566.7$$

in agreement with your second approach.